# How do we load tinymce in angular 2 component html file dynamically?

Tags: angular

Iam trying to load TinyMce in the component. When iam doing a static add iam able to add it into the html file. In the same way when iam trying to append the html tag dynamically into the html file iam unable to view the TinyMce. Below given is the code iam using to add the TinyMce dynamically into the HTML file.

```js
tiny.component.ts

import {
  Component,
  OnDestroy,
  AfterViewInit,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  Output
} from '@angular/core';
declare var tinymce: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'simple-tiny',
  templateUrl: 'tiny.component.html'
})
export class SimpleTinyComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Output() onEditorKeyup = new EventEmitter<any>();
  htmlToAdd: string;

  constructor(){
  this.htmlToAdd = '<div class="two">two</div>';
  }
  editor;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '.editable',
      plugins: ['link', 'paste', 'table'],
      menubar: false,
      setup: editor => {
        this.editor = editor;
        editor.on('keyup', () => {
          const content = editor.getContent();
          this.onEditorKeyup.emit(content);
        });
      },
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    tinymce.remove(this.editor);
  }
  add(){
    this.htmlToAdd = this.htmlToAdd+'<div class="editable1">three</div>';
   this.ngAfterViewInit();
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '.editable1',
      plugins: ['link', 'paste', 'table'],
      toolbar1: 'undo | bold italic |  link forecolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | fontselect fontsizeselect custombutton',
      inline: true,
            setup: editor => {
        this.editor = editor;
        editor.on('keyup', () => {
          const content = editor.getContent();
          this.onEditorKeyup.emit(content);
        });
      }
      });
  }
}
```

```html
<h2 class="editable" >Editable header</h2>
<div class="" [innerHtml]="htmlToAdd"></div>
<button (click)='add()'>Add</button>
```